# installing axios in react not longer supported?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, macos, npm

After running npm create-react-app and trying to install axios I get this log:

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'i', 'axios' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v12.19.0
4 verbose npm-session c635d5e453ae3bb7
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/axios 143ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for axios@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ch":"^1.0.0","grunt-e'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1617ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ch":"^1.0.0","grunt-e'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50
11 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
12 verbose cwd /Users/juancastillo/Desktop/testingaxios
13 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
14 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "axios"
15 verbose node v12.19.0
16 verbose npm  v6.14.8
17 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ch":"^1.0.0","grunt-e'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

does anyone know why I can't run npm i axios on my create-react-app ?

npm v = 6.14.8

node v = 12.19.0

shell = /bin/zsh
macOS Catalina = v10.15.7

Comment: Can you include also your package.json file?

Comment: delete the node_modules and try it again?

Comment: @DrewReese there is nothing there other than the default dependencies when your run create-react-app, I thought it was a npm problem but i ran npm install materialui/core and it worked fine. Do you guys think it has to do anything with switching from bash to zsh?

Comment: Right, but I've seen similar issues to what you describe when *somewhere* in the middle of the installation of a package and your package.json file is being updated, and that *this* update gets borked and now you've invalid JSON and later the installation fails. The package (axios) was still installed to the local node_modules, but left the package.json file with error.

Comment: @DrewReese Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...ch":"^1.0.0","grunt-e' was the error I got in the terminal and it was solved with a simple npm cache clean --force. Thank you for your time looking into it